# On Complex Improper Integrals and Rectifiable Paths

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, solution-verification, contour-integration, complex-integration

I would like to know if we may generalize both definite and improper complex integral as follows:

I tried to write as Conway does in his book.

Let's define a path in $U \cup \partial{U}$, $\Gamma$, as follows

$$\Gamma: [0,1] \to U \cup \partial{U} \\ u \mapsto \Gamma(u) = p(z) + u \cdot [q(z) - p(z)]$$

Let $g: U \to \mathbb{C}$ and $p,q: D \to U \cup \partial{U}$ both analytic on their open and connected domains, and $G: U \cup \partial{U} \to \mathbb{C}$, primitive of $g$. Then $I$ converges for every $z \in D$.

$$ I: D \to \mathbb{C}  \\z \mapsto I(z) = \int_\Gamma g(s)\,ds = G(q(z)) - G(p(z)), \\ \Gamma: [0,1] \to U \cup \partial{U} \\ u \mapsto \Gamma(u) = p(z) + u \cdot [q(z) - p(z)]\\ \, \\$$

The main question: **Is this how complex improper integrals are defined? I.e., we define a path which one of its end point is at the boundary of the integrand's domain? Is there anything missing?** Most books emphazise solving complex improper integrals via residues, but that's not what I want now.

**Does $\Gamma$ need to be rectifiable? I guess it is already**

As far as I know, we have the following possibilities:

**P1** $I(z)$ will be a definite integral, if  $z \in D$ such that $p(z), q(z) \in U$.

**P2** On the other hand, $I(z)$ will be an improper integral, if $ z \in D$ such that $ p(z) \lor q(z) \in \partial{U}$. Would this be correct?

From Conway's Graduate book, we have Theorem 1.18 (which I'm using as an example):

Let $G$ be open in $\mathbb{C}$ and let $\gamma$ be a rectifiable path in $G$ with initial and end points $\alpha$ and $\beta$ resceptively. If $f: G \to \mathbb{C}$ is a continuous function with a primitive $F:G \to \mathbb{C}$, then

$$\int_\gamma f = F(\beta)-F(\alpha)$$

(Recall that $F$ is a *primitive* of $f$ when $F'=f$.)

I have read the whole chapter, but no detailed explanation was found. Thus, any other references would be appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT** It's been a while since the bounty started and no answers. I'm starting to think that my question is "wrong" somehow. Please comment anything that may be corrected. Thanks again

**EDIT 2** If $g$ is analytic on its open domain $U$, shouldn't it be also at $\partial{U}$? If so, we may use the Theorem 1.18. Right?

Comment: Why are you writing $+$ for $\cup$?

Comment: I'll correct that, thank you! I'll check how to write in LaTeX.

Comment: $\cup$ "\cup" ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @mjw, thank you. It had been modified already.

Comment: @Mr.N, yes, looks great!

Comment: Since you haven't gotten any answers in a couple of days, I'll give my two cents. I don't find the question very clear. D is used way before it's almost accidentally defined a paragraph later; the question is written backwards in numerous other places, like where $\Gamma$ is defined after it's been used; the notation is not particularly clear, e.g. $\Gamma$ is really a family of paths depending on $z$; I don't understand how $\Gamma_z$ for a given $z$ could possibly fail to be rectifiable since it's just a linear interpolation; etc.

Comment: Hello, @JoshuaP.Swanson. I have fixed some problems. I defined the stuff before using. In here, I allow $\Gamma$ to be any path that connects $p(z)$ to $q(z)$ for any $z \in U \cup \partial{U}$. Thanks

Comment: People usually restrict to piecewise-smooth paths (this suffices for all complex analysis purposes) in which case the relevant integral is defined as $\int_\gamma f(z)dz:=\int_a^b f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt$. Things will also work reasonably well for absolutely continuous paths but you have to know Lebesgue integration. For general rectifiable paths you might encounter some unpleasant surprises. Why Conway wants to deal with these, I have no idea.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, thanks for your answer. Well, this way seems simpler. But I'm still unsure about the difference between "piecewise-smooth paths", "absolutely continuous paths" and rectifiable ones and how they allow me to define path integrals. May I ask you some references on them specifically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My favorite reference for this is Rudin's book "Real and complex analysis." Instead of "rectifiable" Rudin says "bounded variation." Piecewise $C^1$ curve  implies absolutely continuous, which in turn implies bounded variation. But all these implications are not reversible. For a basic course in Complex Analysis, I strongly advise using piecewise-$C^1$-smooth curves and avoid all the complications coming from the more general notions.

Now, a curve $\gamma: I\to {\mathbb C}$ is piecewise $C^1$-smooth if it is continuous and its domain can be subdivided into intervals $I_k$ such that $\gamma$ is $C^1$ on each closed subinterval $I_k$ (but its left/right derivatives at the subdivision points may differ). Thus, each piecewise $C^1$-curve is continuously differentiable except for a discrete subset of its domain, an interval $I$ (bounded or unbounded). This allows you to get by the Riemann integral which is what likely you learned in  a calculus/real analysis class. Given a continuous function  $f$ on $\gamma(I)$, you can define the integral
$$
\int_\gamma f(z)dz
$$
as
$$
\int_a^b f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t)dt.
$$
You can also define this integral using an approximation procedure using line segments, as you probably saw in a calculus/ complex analysis class. The answer will be the same.

This makes sense since the integrand is defined and is continuous everywhere except for the subdivision points $t_k$ (where $\gamma'(t)$ is undefined). However, since the one-sided derivatives of $\gamma'_\pm(t_k)$ are assumed to exist and $\gamma'$ is continuous on each $[t_k, t_{k+1}]$, you get an integral (possibly improper) of the type you encountered in a calculus class. One still needs to take care of improper integration in case $I$ is unbounded or is not closed, but this becomes a "calculus issue."

More generally, things also work pretty much the same way when $\gamma$ is absolutely continuous, the formula
$$
\int_a^b f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t)dt
$$
still makes sense, but you have to be aware of the fact that $\gamma'(t)$ exists only "almost everywhere" and in order to define this integral, Riemann integration is not enough, you need Lebesgue integral.

A nice thing about absolutely continuous functions (whatever they are, see Rudin's book for the precise definition), is that you can assume that the ordinary rules of calculus apply; in particular, the length of $\gamma$ is still given by the formula
$$
\int_a^b |\gamma'(t)|dt. 
$$
Just remember that the integral is more complicated than the one you learned in a calculus class.

A general rectifiable function is a BV (bounded variation) function and you only have the inequality
$$
\int_a^b |\gamma'(t)|dt \le length(\gamma).  
$$
You can have a monotonic (hence, BV) continuous function $\gamma: [0,1]\to [0,1]$ satisfying $\gamma(0)=0, \gamma(1)=1$, but $\gamma'(t)=0$ almost everywhere, which means that the integral of the derivative vanishes, but the curve, of course, has unit length. Such issues one should avoid while learning basic complex analysis.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and book recommendation! Just one more thing: as in my example, if $f$ is analytic on $\gamma(I)$ (a piecewise $C$^1 path), except at gamma's end point $t_f$, where $t_f$ is a non-removable singularity of $f$. Could I define the integral as you defined earlier? Would this result lead to an improper complex integral?

Comment: @Mr.N: Yes, it would be an improper integral, defined as a limit of proper integrals $\int_a^T$, $T\to b-$. There is no guarantee, in general, that this limit exists or is finite.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, recommendation and patience. I'll try my best to read this book and see if the $\Gamma$ in my example fits well the definition and also learn Lebesgue integration.